# React useInfiniteQuery calls multiple times based on previously fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a created conversation list. When user click on the list, based on the id from the list, a chat messages view open's beside the chat. There i used infinite scroll, so that by scrolling user can see their previous messages. User views previous message of that created conversation list by scrolling up. But when user click's another conversation from the list, api hit based on the previous pageParams like if user viewed previous messages for 3 page or 4 page, next api calls 3 times or 4 times based on previous offset. My code is,

```
const getData = async (params, pageParam) => {
    const { channelId, apiFor, page_limit, offset } = params

    const { data } = await MainApi.get(
        `/customer/message/details?${apiFor}=${
            channelId === 'admin' ? 0 : channelId
        }?&offset=${pageParam}&limit=${page_limit}`
    )
    return data
}
export const useGetConversation = (params) => {
    return useInfiniteQuery(
        'get_conversation',
        ({ pageParam = params.offset }) => getData(params, pageParam),
        {
            getNextPageParam: (lastPage, allPages) => {
                const nextPage = allPages.length + 1
                return lastPage.messages.length > 0 ? nextPage : undefined
            },
            enabled: false,
            onError: onErrorResponse,
        }
    )
}
```

why second time, api hits multiple times based on the previous pageParams?

Comment: The code you posted looks fine (apart from the `enabled: false`, why?). Could you share a complete, minimal example in codesandbox?

Comment: You should be providing an unique identifier for each conversation (like an id) and include it in the query key array. Otherwise, you are just writing to the same cache entry each time you switch conversations.